# Conservation of energy vs. force equations in circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

[image]when studying for a mechanics exam I got really confused with one of the questions in my textbook. At first glance it seemed like an obvious conservation of energy problem, however that led me to the wrong answer. Id really appreciate if someone could find the error in my solution.

Question:
A kid with mass $m$ swings, without initial velocity, across pond with a massless rope with length $l$. The rope makes the angle $\theta$ with the horizontal. Determine if the boy can make it across the pond if the rope can tolerate $S_{max} = \frac{3mg}{2}$. Especially if the angle is $\alpha = 30^o$. If the rope can't tolerate the stress, determine the angle $\theta$.

My solution:

State the force equation in the lowest point:

$S = \frac{mv^2}{l} + mg$

Finding $v$ in the lowest point. All the potential energy in the initial point is converted to kinetic energy.

$lgm(1-\sin\theta) = \frac{mv^2}{2} \rightarrow v = \sqrt{2lg(1-\sin\theta)}$

Substituting this into the first equation yields,

$S = \frac{2gl(1-\sin\theta)}{l}m + mg \rightarrow S = 3-2\sin\theta = 3/2$

$S = \arcsin\frac{3}{4} \approx 49^o$

the correct answer is $56^0$

Comment: i can't make any sense of your question. what's $\alpha$? is $\theta$ the angle the rope makes when the kid is at rest? a sketch would help

Comment: Alright, I've added a sketch. Yes, $\theta$ is the angle when the kid is at rest. Thanks for helping :D

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 1):

let $S$ be the tension force. At the lowest point (where tension is highest), you have that $$\dfrac{mv^2}r = S - mg$$ which is just the net centripital force. Since $S$ is maxed, sub in $S_\mathrm{max}$ and get
$$\dfrac{mv^2}r = S_{\rm max} - mg$$ to solve for $\theta$.

Comment: But that makes me run into the same problem again. From your equation: $\frac{v^2}{l} = \frac{g}{2}$, which substituted into my equation yields the same result.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. The sinus function is an odd function so $\sin\theta = -\frac{3}{4} \rightarrow  \theta = -48^0$ and thus not the right answer.

Comment: please disregard that edit, i made a careless mistake. @juggernugger however, i did do the problem and got your answer. are you sure your posted answer is correct?

Comment: yes I think so, there is however another way to go about solving this problem by applying force equations and integrate. Was that your problem solving method, or did you use conservation of energy?

Comment: i used conservation of energy. but this is a simple problem --  max tension occurs at the bottom where speed is greatest, and then one uses force analysis from there. nonetheless, the conservation of energy method would obviously apply here and should yield the correct result.

Comment: Yes exactly! That's why I find it so frustrating that I can't get the right answer. But if you solved it using conservation of energy, I must have done some error in my calculations. Can you spot it?

Comment: i got the same answer as you did @juggernugger  49$^\circ$

Comment: ohh right, i thought that you got the other answer. I have the other solution which supposedly gets the right answer, should I post it?

Comment: @juggernugger please do (assuming you're allowed)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124897/discussion-between-user256872-and-juggernugger).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

State the force equation om the tangential direction

$\dot{v} = g\cos\theta$

applying the chain rule,
$\dot{v} = \frac{dv}{ds}v$, and substituting this into the equation:

$vdv = g\cos\theta ds = gl\cos\theta d\theta$

Integrate:

$\int_{0}^v udu = \int_{\pi/6}^\theta gl\cos\theta d\theta$ (This part I dont really understand; shouldn't the integration limits be $\theta \to \pi/2?$)

$\frac{v^2}{2} = gl(\sin\theta - 0.5)$

which substituted in the general force equation in the normal direction

$S = \frac{mv^2}{l}+mg\sin\theta$,

gives

$\frac{3}{2} = 3\sin\theta - 1 \to \theta = \arcsin\frac{5}{6} \approx 56^0$

Comment: the confusion stems from your $\alpha$. That would be the $\pi /6$ in the integral limit. though I'm not sure what that represents....

Comment: yea, you're probably right, I figured the same. Seems weird tho...

Comment: Ah, i think  got it!!

Comment: Our conservation of energy method wasn't wrong, we were just finding different things. The question was quite poorly phrased but I will repost it

Comment: haha alright, thanks for helping me. :D

Comment: Ohh, wait... The rope does break; it breaks at $\theta = 56^0$. I totally misunderstood the question myself, hence the poorly phrased question.

Answer (score 0):

This question was quite poorly worded. Here is what it's really asking:

> Suppose a boy holds on to a rope of some length $l$, making an angle of $\alpha=30^\circ$ with the horizontal. He is at rest, then lets go and swings. Suppose that the rope can withstand a maximal tension force of $S_{\rm max}=\dfrac{3mg}2$. Can the boy make the swing, or will the rope break, if so for what angle $\theta$ (measured from the horizontal)?

Our approaches were fine. What we tried to find is the smallest possible angle so that the rope does not break (yes, the way we define $\theta$, the smaller $\theta$, the higher the likely hood of our rope breaking). Given that our minimal angle is greater than the 30$^\circ$, then we know that the rope must break. The question is, for what angle? You can use conservation of energy for that. However, the tension equation will need some tweaking, namely $$\dfrac{mv^2}r = S - mg\sin\theta$$ where the $mg\sin\theta$ gives us the centripetal component of gravity -- since we're not sure where the rope will break.

Comment: Yes I get It now. Our calculations weren't wrong after all.